# Finding all functions such that $\vert{f(x) - f(y)}\vert = \vert{x-y}\vert$

Tags: calculus

$\left\lvert{{f(x) - f(y)}\over{x-y}}\right\rvert = 1$

$\displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0}{\left\lvert{{f(x+h) - f(x)}\over{h}}\right\rvert}$ $=1$

Now the main problem is bringing the limit inside the absolute value function.
For that we require:

$1.$ $f(x) = \vert{x}\vert$ is continuous at the input, which is true as it is continuous everywhere

$2.$ The function inside the absolute value, i.e  $g(y) =$ ${f(x+y) - f(x)}\over{y}$ is continuous at $y = 0$

I'm having trouble proving point 2.It's not hard to prove $f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$, but that is not sufficient.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/598767/42969

Comment: @MartinR that post does not justify bringing the limit inside the absolute value, and the answer is just saying that it isn't obvious

Comment: $f$ is a continuous injective function on $\mathbb R$ which implies that it's monotone on $\mathbb R$. Depends on whether it's increasing or decreasing, either $f(x) -f(y) = x-y$ or $f(x)-f(y) = y-x$ for all $x,y$. Using either of these implications, 2. is obvious, but one won't even need it to find all such $f$ anyway.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: In this particular case one can show it directly, without using continuity or injectivity. But apparently something is wrong with my answer.

Comment: @MartinR Just noticed it while I wrote it. Your answer is right.

Comment: The easiest approach to solve this problem is Von Eitzen's: He says at the end of his answer to the related question: "You can solve the problem without differentiation for example by considering $f(0),f(1), f(x)$." Doing so gives you a simple "proof by contradiction". There's no need to consider differentiation, which is more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $f$ is differentiable with $|f'(x)| = 1$ you need to show that $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ can only take one of the values $+1$ or $-1$, but not both.

This can be done as follows: For $x < y < z$ is
$$
\begin{align}
 |f(z)-f(x)| &\overset{(*)}{\le} |f(z)-f(y)| + |f(y)-f(x)|  \\
&= (z-y) + (y-x) \\
&= z-x \\
&= |f(z)-f(x)|
\end{align}
$$
so that *equality* holds at the triangle inequality $(*)$, and that is only the case if $f(y)-f(x)$ and $f(z)-f(y)$ have the *same sign.*

It follows that either

- $\forall x, y \in \Bbb R: x < y \implies f(y) -f(x) > 0$ (i.e. $f$ is increasing), or
- $\forall x, y \in \Bbb R: x < y \implies f(y) -f(x) < 0$ (i.e. $f$ is decreasing).

Now you can conclude that $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$ can only take one of the values $+1$ or $-1$, but not both.

It follows that $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x) = 1$ or $f'(x) = -1$, but that is not even needed: Setting $y = 0$ in
$$
 \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = c = \pm 1
$$
gives
$$
 f(x) = f(0) + cx \, .
$$